# Groups and Subgroups, operations within subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$, $K$, $N$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H$$\subseteq$$N$. Then prove that $(HK)$$\cap$$N$ $=$ $H$$($$K\cap$$N$$)$.

Solution : At first, we took a point $h_1$$\in$$H$ and $k_1$$\in$$K$. Then $h_1$$k_1$$\in$$HK$. Since $H$$\subseteq$$N$, $h_1$$\in$$N$ also. Then $HK$ $=$ $NK$. Now we are stucked. Please help.

Comment: You haven't proved $HK=NK$, only $HK\subseteq NK$.

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $(HK)\cap N$. Then $x=ab$ for some $a$ in $H$ and some $b$ in $K$, and also $x$ is in $N$. So $ab$ is in $N$, and $a$ is in $N$ (since $a$ isin $H$, and $H\subseteq N$), so $b$ is in $N$ (since $N$ is a group). Thus, $b$ is in $K\cap N$, and $x=ab$ is in $H(K\cap N)$.

So, that's half of it. You want to try the other half now?

Comment: Thank you. I got the other half.